# illegal use of variable in erlang map

Tags: erlang

How can we create a map inside a function, then pass it as an argument to another function in erlang?

I was trying it in the following code:

```
-module(maps_all).
-export([test_my_map/2]).

test_my_map(K, V) ->
    io:fwrite('~w ~w ~n done.',[K, V]),
    nested_func(#{K => V}).

nested_func(MyMap) ->
    io:fwrite('In nested function as map ~n ~w',[MyMap]).
```

This throws the error:

```
31> c(maps_all).
maps_all.erl:6: illegal use of variable 'K' in map
error
```

Comment: It should be available with R18.

Answer (score 3):

Also, this [was added](http://www.erlang.org/news/85) in Erlang 18 RC

Answer (score 1):

For now (Erlang R17) there is no way to use variable directly in map expression.
You can achieve this with maps: [new](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#new-0) and [put](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#put-3):

```
nested_func(maps:put(K, V, maps:new()))
```